sort slice of Pandas Series including index
I have the following df Series
a    1
b    4
c    3
d    2

and would like to sort the last three rows including the index.
df[1:] = df[1:].sort_values

gives
a    1
b    2
c    3
d    4

which does not change the index, as I would expect. How can I solve this?

I suspect that slicing does not respect alignment

Code
use concat
n = 3
out = pd.concat([s[:-n], s[-n:].sort_values()])

out:
a    1
d    2
c    3
b    4

Example Code
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([1, 4, 3, 2], index=list('abcd'))


Another possible solution, which:

First, creates a sorted version of the last three elements of the Series (from index 1 onward).

Then, updates the original series by assigning the sorted values back to the same slice.

Finally, adjusts the index of the series by creating a new index list that combines the original first index (at position 0) with the sorted indices from the last three elements


sort = df.iloc[1:].sort_values()
    
df.iloc[1:] = sort.values 
df.index = [df.index[0]] + list(sort.index) 

Or, more concisely:
sort = df.iloc[1:].sort_values()
df.iloc[1:], df.index = sort.values, [df.index[0]] + list(sort.index)


Output:
a    1
d    2
c    3
b    4
dtype: int64


An efficient approach would be to use the slice to reorder the indices, then to reindex:
ser = pd.Series([1, 4, 3, 2], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

s = slice(1, None) # [1:]

idx = ser.index.tolist()
idx[s] = ser[s].sort_values().index

ser = ser.reindex(idx)

Output:
a    1
d    2
c    3
b    4
dtype: int64

An advantage is that this also works with any slice, not just contiguous ones:
ser = pd.Series([3, 4, 2, 1], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

s = slice(0, None, 2) # [0::2]

idx = ser.index.tolist()
idx[s] = ser[s].sort_values().index

ser = ser.reindex(idx)

Output:
c    2
b    4
a    3
d    1
dtype: int64

with a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [3, 4, 2, 1]}, index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

s = slice(1, None)

idx = df.index.tolist()
idx[s] = df['col'].iloc[s].sort_values().index

df = df.reindex(idx)

   col
a    3
d    1
c    2
b    4

